# Outlook New Meeting - Defaulting to Scheduling Assistant

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, meetings

Good Day,

I'm stumped on a ticket that I'm currently dealing with, where the individual goes to their Outlook O365, into their Calendar, hits "New Meeting" and is automatically thrown into the "Scheduling Assistant" screen of the new meeting window. This is the first time they've run into this issue, and it just recently started happening and now happens each time. What can I do to get this back to normal for my customer?

Any assistance is appreciated! Cheers!

P.S. - These images are my recreation of what the person is running into.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdbS7.png - New Meeting

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUyGf.png - Straight to "Scheduling Assistant"

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your Outlook 365? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

Based on my test in my Outlook 365(version 2109(Build 14430.20234)), the main page of the meeting will be displayed normally instead of the "scheduling assistant" page when I click create new meeting in the calendar, which does not reproduce your issue. Dose this issue occur with specific user or everyone around you? If is a special user, please check the difference between his outlook client and others' outlook client, such as the installed third-party programs.

And I noticed that the issue occurred recently, have you done any specific operations before that, such as run any script?

Considering the impact of some add ins, It is suggested that you try to start outlook in safe mode(win+R>type: outlook /safe) to check whether it works normally.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- First open a calendar appointment.
- Right click the Appointment tab and choose customize ribbon.
- Grab the Appointment item and drag it to the top of the main tabs list.
- This will resolve and open the 'meeting' first when opening a calendar appointment